# MS Access setting to ignore date conversion error

Tags: ms-access, date, importerror

An Access DB imports a fixed width text file; one column is mostly dates.
When the date is not available, the file's creator actually uses the string "Null"
Access puts the row in the table with that field actually null.

But, when the files started coming with different field widths, I copied the DB, tweaked the starting/width values in the input spec, and imported.  NOW, all the rows with null get logging in (table)_import_errors as an error converting text to date.

I have found no setting (not that I changed any) to explain it.  One difference is that although both DBs are in Access 2000 format, the original is on a machine that still has Access 2000, while the new one is being handled by Access 2003.

Is that a behavior change in the Access version?  Is pre-processing the file the only solution?

---

Thanks, David.  That's what I would have done (except for the Excel part) if it had not fixed itself.  I posted that, but apparently someone didn't like the public admission that Access has bugs.

The only thing that changed was that two  *other* columns in the fixed width plain text input was wider.  Yet Access "decided" to discard the whole row instead of just the date field for three consecutive attempts.  The fourth time, it still reported it as an error but imported the rest of the row.

So, when Access misbehaves for no good reason, try again a time or two, then try explicitly coding the conversion from text.

Comment: I haven't a clue what you're talking about by your insinuation that somebody deleted something of yours because you suggested Access has bugs. It's a pretty serious allegation.

Comment: Access isn't "misbehaving" here -- it's acting as it has been designed to do. That you don't know how to tell it how to do things properly is not a flaw in Access.

Comment: 1. Comment vs. answer: Because for some reason, stackoverflow that day would not allow me to post a comment.

Comment: 2. The reason for the question is that Access began discarding records/rows with the conversion error. The "before" behavior was to report a converion error, and discard only that field. When the prior behavior returned after several tries, I posted that fact, but someone deleted it. As to **why** they deleted it, that was just a guess. But I definitely saw it on the site after posting, but by the time you answered, it was gone.

Comment: 3. Misbehaving: Aren't you taking Access a little personally?  I changed the **WIDTH** of a couple of columns in an input spec, and Access changed its rules for interpreting the string "Null" in one of the other columns.  Then, with **NO** further change from me, Access went back to handling "Null" the way it did before.  I call that misbehaving.

Comment: I call that pilot error -- Access didn't make the change by itself. Or, you didn't understand the implications of the changes you made.

Comment: Help me understand the "implications" of why changing the width of one column should change the interpretation of another.  Even better, the implications of changing it back when _nothing_ was changed in the file or input spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. Use a buffer field or buffer table that imports the date field into a text field. Then you can process that into the appropriate values in the final destination field.
2. Use a SQL import instead of DoCmd.TransferText. What you do in that case is use a connect string in the FROM clause so you can then process the date field in your SELECT:

```
  SELECT Sheet1.FirstField, Replace(Sheet2.DateField, "NULL", Null) As DateField 
  FROM Sheet1 IN 'C:\Import\Spreadsheet.xls'[Excel 5.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;];
```

Convert that into an INSERT query and you're golden.